# ShowDialog causes heap error

Tags: c++, winforms

I have a COM server (out-of-process) in which I call ShowDialog() of an FolderBrowserDialog (C++, WindowsForms). When I then want to stop the COM server, it crashes, saying there is a heap error. If I just create the FolderBRowserDialog without calling ShowDialog, the error doesn't occure... When doing research I read something about having to dispose manually, but the dispose method cannot be called. Using delete does also not fix my problem. Any ideas? Here is the code snippet:

```
...
FolderBrowserDialog^ fbd = gcnew FolderBrowserDialog(); 
fbd->Description = "MAS Open dialog";
fbd->RootFolder = Environment::SpecialFolder::MyComputer;
fbd->SelectedPath = Str;
...
res = fbd->ShowDialog(gcnew WindowWrapper(hwnd));
...
```

Comment: That's not C++. Is it C++/CLI?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, you have to call

```
delete fbd;
```

after **ShowDialog**.